# Why in python struct.pack("B",9) and struct.pack("B",10) produce '\t' and '\n' as output ?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working with struct library in python. I have come across one unusual thing while using pack function of struct library. Tested in ubuntu. I checked the ASCII table where I found that TAB and Line Feed has ASCII value 9 and 10 respectively. But why for other values no such equivalent character is being shown ?

```
import struct
struct.pack("B",0)
'\x00'

struct.pack("B",8)
'\x08'

struct.pack("B",9)
'\t' # why ???    

struct.pack("B",10)
'\n' # why ????

struct pack("B",11)
'\x0b'
```

Answer (score 1):

This has absolutely nothing to do with the struct module: it's simply how the `repr()` of string objects chooses to display unprintable characters.

```
>>> [chr(i) for i in range(8,12)]
['\x08', '\t', '\n', '\x0b']
```

While all of the control characters have names, most of them are of historical interest only.  Only a few with consistent meanings have a single-character backslash escape sequence in Python (and most other languages); as a convenience, Python uses those escape sequences when displaying a string, rather than the general-purpose hexadecimal escape.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no equivalent character for 0, 8, and 11.

It is not the `sruct.pack` that is the issue, it is the representation of the bit pattern when it is converted to a string.  If you enter `struct.pack("B",10)` in an interactive session then python has to convert to a string, and in that case it uses `__repr__()` to do it.  `print`, on the other hand, uses `__str__()` and might give a different result:

try:

```
print struct.pack("B",10)
```

you will get a blank line displayed.  Always remember that displaying any object only shows a text representation of the value.